# The site sees incomprehensible frames, how to remove them?

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWrUT.png)
the development of the website has been driven into an incomprehensible framework, and cannot align itself in the center

we tried to change the nav elements in the center of the channel, but we did not achieve anything

```css
.filter0 h2{
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #490E84;
    text-align: center;
}                
.filter0 h3{
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 90px;
    color: hsl(0, 80%, 52%);
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
   <nav class="filter0">
                        <h2 class="p-cart">Книга - друг человека</h2>
                        <h3 cldss="p-cartyy">Берите книги у нас в аренду</h3>
                              
                           
                            <form>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Искать здесь...">
                                <button type="submit"></button>
                            </form> 
    
                    </nav>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "framework"? Can you share the code involved, and a better explanation for these "incomprehensible frames"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193) you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.